# Updating subdocuments in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have the following schema definition in mongo:

```
   const sampleSendingDetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      recipient: String,
      packageDetails: {
        service: String,
        trackingNumber: String
      }, ....
```

I want to update the mongo database in a single call, something like:

```
{  
    "recipient": "fiocruz",
  "packageDetails": {
    "service": "Sedex",
    "trackingNumber": "asdsfdfdsfdsfrt"
  },
```

See that sampleSendingDetailsSchema is already a subdocument. So packageDetails is a sub sub document. I have tried to update as presented, but it does not work. If I try:

```
{  
    "recipient": "fiocruz",...
```

Then it works, of course, the packageDetails will not be updated in this last case because no information was provided. Anyone has a hint how to update sub sub documents in mongo. I have found some questions, but they are all old, I am  not sure mongo solved the problem.

Comment: Can you give a sample doc & expected result, What's wrong with using `.` notation ?

Comment: Hi there, I solved the problem, thanks! I gave up and decided to use an one-level approach. I remember I had the same problem before, maybe there is no solution now for this issue in mongo.